# Symfony : get entities id in a form with collection element

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I'm setting a form with a Collection element. I set the prototype as described in [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

I have set my javascript to manage the dynamic add/delete part.

But I want to add, as a data-elementid, the entity id of the saved elements, because i want to perform an ajax check (during the form filling, not at the submit stage) for already saved collection elements if some field change. So i need to give the entity id to the DOm to be passed to the data.

```
<form ...>

<ul class="tariffAdjustments ulprototype" data-prototype="{{ protos.tariffAdjustment_prototype(form.tariffAdjustments.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
  {% for tariffAdjustment in form.tariffAdjustments %}
  <li class="eltariffadjustment" data-taid="XXX">
    {# can't retrieve the element id #}{{dump(form.tariffAdjustments.vars)}}
    {{ protos.tariffAdjustment_prototype(tariffAdjustment)|raw }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

</form>
```

In the `{{dump(form.tariffAdjustments.vars)}}` i have :

```
FormView {#18167 
  +vars: array:30 [
    "value" => PersistentCollection {#9714}
    "form" => FormView {#18167}
    "id" => "module_entity_tariffAdjustments"
    ...
    "prototype" => FormView {#18189 ▼
      +vars: array:27 [▼
        "id" => "module_entity_tariffAdjustments___name__"
        ...
      ]
      +parent: FormView {#18167}
      +children: array:10 []
        "name" => FormView {#18192}     <= entity field exposed in the FormType
        "startDate" => FormView {#18197}
        ...
      -rendered: false
    }
  ]
  +parent: FormView {#8546 ▶}
  +children: array:3 [▼
    0 => FormView {#18336 ▼
      +vars: array:27 [▼
        "value" => TariffAdjustment {#9798 ▼
          -id: 154      <= what i'm looking for
          ...
        }
        ...
      ]
      +parent: FormView {#18167}
      +children: array:10 []
      -rendered: false
    }
    1 => FormView {#18338 ▼
      +vars: array:27 [▼
        "value" => TariffAdjustment {#9798 ▼
          -id: 172      <= what i'm looking for
          ...
        }
        ...
      ]
      +parent: FormView {#18167}
      +children: array:10 []
      -rendered: false
    }
  ]
  -rendered: false
}
```

My entity Id is obviously not in my FormType : i don't want to set it.

---

### EDIT

The main form

```
class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $em = $options['entity_manager'];
    $builder
      ->add('tariffAdjustments', CollectionType::class, [
        'label' => 'module.tariffAdjustments',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => [
          'class' => 'collectiondata',
        ],
        'constraints' => new Valid(),
        'entry_type' => TariffAdjustmentType::class,
        'entry_options' => ['entity_manager' => $em],
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
      ]);
  }
}
```

And the Collection Form

```
class TariffAdjustmentType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $em = $options['entity_manager'];
    $builder
      ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'name',
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mandatory'],
        'required' => true,
      ]);
    ...
  }
}
```

Maybe i missed something obvious but i can't find what.
Thanks

Comment: Please add back-end code of your form, instead of dump of the FormView, it's not really useful. If you don't use the ID as choice value, then you can add it as additional parameter. 

Look https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr

Comment: i've updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

How stupid of me :

i was setting `{{dump(form.tariffAdjustments.vars)}}`
but since i'm in the loop i just had to set : `tariffAdjustment.vars.value.id` which is the id of the entity i looked for.